# Como criar uma aplicação em Vue?

Tags: vue.js, github, webpack

Estou tentando seguir as instruções desse site para criar uma aplicação em Vue: [Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter#typescript-vue-starter)

O problema é que eu não entendo o que ele necessita que eu faça primeiro. Devo baixar o arquivo do github? Ele me pede para instalar o Webpack e o Vue, mas onde consigo isso(procurei no site deles mas não encontrei)?
Nesta parte do site ele fala:

> You'll want to bring your TypeScript files together - both the code you'll be writing 
>       as well as any necessary declaration files. To do this, you'll need to create a `"tsconfig.json"` which contains a list of your input files as well as all your compilation settings. Simply create a new file in your project root named tsconfig.json and fill it with the following contents:

Eu não entendi o que ele me pediu. pois eu só copiei os comandos em `bash` que tinha no site, então não encontrei nenhum arquivo com esse nome. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz nisso?

PS: Eu pediria para o meu professor, mas ele não iria me ajudar, já tentei

Comment: Não tenho certeza se isso se enquadra no site. Os comandos que você executa no `bash` são apenas para instalar as dependências, se você rodou o `npm install <nome da dependência>`, você já tem TypeScript e Vue. Esse arquivo `tsconfig.json` é para você mesmo criar, nele você declara algumas regras para definir o comportamento do `TypeScript`. E sim, a ideia é criar esses arquivos seguindo o exemplo do tutorial.

Comment: É tanta informação junta no tutorial que eu acabo me perdendo fácil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, vamos do começo.

**NPM**

Primeiro você instala o NPM se ainda nao tiver:

https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

**VUE**

Com NPM instalado na maquina, siga esses passos:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html

- Com o terminal aberto digite:

  `npm install vue`

Pronto você ja tem o `VueJs` rodando na maquina.

Recomendo você criar os projetos com base no `VueCli` que já traz muitas coisas prontas.

**Install VueCli**

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

- Rode no terminal

`npm install -g @vue/cli`

**Criando um projeto com base no @Vue/cli**

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html

- No terminal rode

`vue create nome-projeto`
ex: `vue create dup-web`

o VueCli vai te fazer varias perguntas de configurações como:

- Babel, Eslint etc.

Depois disso, o terminal ira te orientar a dar um

`cd nome-projeto`

e depois:

`npm run serve`

Acredito que seja isso.